# JComboBox. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, methods, jcombobox

My code is returning the value of `c` as null! What is wrong with it?

I want the value of the index to be added to the string `c`, but it is not happening and even the first code of `System.out.println("C: "+c+" A: "+a+" B: "+b);` is returning all the variables as 0!

```
public String getData(){
String c ;
    c = null;
int a = cb1.getSelectedIndex();
int b = cb2.getSelectedIndex();
 System.out.println("C: "+c+" A: "+a+" B: "+b);
    if (a == 1 && b == 1) {
        c=""+a;
    } else if (a == 1 && b == 2) {
        c=""+a;
    } else if (a == 2 && b == 1) {
        c=""+a;
    } else if (a == 2 && b == 2) {
        c=""+a;
    } else if (a == 3 && b == 1) {
        c=""+a;
    } else if (a == 4 && b == 1) {
        c=""+a;
    } else if (a == 4 && b == 2) {
        c="";
    } else if (a == 5 && b == 1) {
        c=""+a+""+b; 
    } else if (a == 5 && b == 2) {
        c=""+a+""+b;
    } else if (a == 6 && b == 1) {
        c=""+a+""+b;
    } else if (a == 7 && b == 1) {
        c=""+a+""+b;
    } else if (a == 8 && b == 1) {
        c=""+a+""+b;
    } else if (a == 8 && b == 2) {
        c=""+a+""+b;
    } else if (a == 8 && b == 3) {
        c=""+a+""+b;
    }


System.out.println("C: "+c+" A: "+a+" B: "+b);

 return c;           
}
```

Comment: Your structure is really bad, please refactor it and post it again ok? Than it would be more easy to find your probs

Comment: Why don't you try put this in a loop ?!

Comment: @Nabeel You know about `else if`, right?

Comment: instead of having a continuous if-else, just use a switch

Comment: @Nabeel you also are doing a SysOut with the Variable c, that Variable is there null!

Comment: what happens when you print a b and c before the if condition? are there any numbers? what is the output? if they are 0 then the data getting in is bad.. since the string returned 0 then that means there is a problem with your input... and please try to reform your code, seems you have more than 1 edit proposal

Comment: @bakriawad the value I am taking is the selected model of a JComboBox hence 'cb1.getSelectedIndex()' but its value comes as 0 even when it shouldn't..

Comment: @Biffen yeah, I do....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed `if {}  else {if {} }` to  `if{} else if {}`

```
public String getData(){
        String c ;
        c = null;
        int a = cb1.getSelectedIndex();
        int b = cb2.getSelectedIndex();
        System.out.println("C: "+c+" A: "+a+" B: "+b);
        if (a == 1 && b == 1) {
            c=""+a;
        } else if (a == 1 && b == 2) {
            c=""+a;
        } else if (a == 2 && b == 1) {
            c=""+a;
        } else if (a == 2 && b == 2) {
            c=""+a;
        } else if (a == 3 && b == 1) {
            c=""+a;
        } else if (a == 4 && b == 1) {
            c=""+a;
        } else if (a == 4 && b == 2) {
            c="";
        } else if (a == 5 && b == 1) {
            c=""+a+""+b; 
        } else if (a == 5 && b == 2) {
            c=""+a+""+b;
        } else if (a == 6 && b == 1) {
            c=""+a+""+b;
        } else if (a == 7 && b == 1) {
            c=""+a+""+b;
        } else if (a == 8 && b == 1) {
            c=""+a+""+b;
        } else if (a == 8 && b == 2) {
            c=""+a+""+b;
        } else if (a == 8 && b == 3) {
            c=""+a+""+b;
        }

    }
```

Please try this code .

You have missed some of the else condition.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your if / else. Wouldn't this do the same thing?
I think you should look at the expected outcome of the scenarios and structure your decision points after that, rather than all the possible combinations of input.

```
    public String getData(){
        String c ;
        c = null;
        int a = cb1.getSelectedIndex();
        int b = cb2.getSelectedIndex();
        System.out.println("C: "+c+" A: "+a+" B: "+b);
        if (a <= 4 && b != 2)
        {
           c=""+a; 
        }
        else if (a >= 5)
        {
           c=""+a+""+b; 
        }
        else
        {
           c="";
        }
    }
```

When there's only 3 different outcomes, you should usually be able to have only 2 decision points in your code. When you feel the need to create that many nested if statements, it's generally a sign that you need to restructure your code

Answer (score 0):

your first systemoutprintln c have to be null...also c is null if nothing is Selected...
also you have to call this method everytime the selection is changing...

try to write not

```
else{
   if{
   } else{
        if{...
```

try to write a nice

```
else if{...}
else if{...}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must convert you integer variables to strings before concatenating them. For example:

```
c=""+a.tostring();
```

Comment: No, this isn't needed, c = "" + a works if a is an int and c is a String. And "int" does not have a toString() method anyway, only Integer does.